# Compare initial opportunity amount to most recent opportunity amount in reports using formulas

Tags: reporting, formula

Im trying to do something thats plagued me for years in salesforce reports.  It feels like it should be relatively simple but for some reason i struggle to get it to actually work.  My actual setup is a little bit different but I'm going to try and use a simpler example of the issue.

Lets say you have an account with a series of opportunities, and what you want to know is the amount change (in a percent) between the initial opportunity and the most recent one, ordered by created date.

My hope is to be able to build a report of Accounts and Opportunities which would allow me to set any date range (Q2 for example) and have a formula field that would calculate the percent change in the amounts between the first opportunity in that range and the last.

I am able to get something similar to this using Opportunity.Amount:Min and Opportunity.Amount:Max but the issue is often times the first opportunity in a date range is not the smallest one, when what i really want is the change between the first and the last.

Feels like I would need some kind of VLookup function or some way to do something like **Opportunity.CreatedDate:Min.Amount - Opportunity.CreatedDate:Max.Amount**

So a simple example for company Acme Corp has the following opportunities

1. Opp 1 - $500 - 1/1/2014
2. Opp 2 - $1250 - 3/1/2014
3. Opp 3 - $100 - 4/4/2014
4. Opp 4 - $1000 - 5/7/2014

What im looking for is a way to automatically calculate the difference between the first opp and the last one, so $1000 - $500 = $500 or a 100% increase

The reason i want this in a report is so if i change the date range in the report to be 2/1/2015 - 5/10/2014 it would update the formulas to be $1000-$1250 = -$250

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to be looking for the `Opportunity.Amount` of the record with the **newest CreatedDate** - record with the **oldest CreatedDate**. The Max and Min Amounts have nothing to do with what you're looking for. It would appear that you want the Amounts for the Opps with **Max** and **Min Dates** that fall within your range.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the history for the Amount field and pull a report on the Opportunity History table, and for the given dates you can get the difference in amount which can be later in report can create a formula field to reflect the percentage of the difference.

Comment: But even in that scenerio you could only compare the max and the min value not the earliest (by date) amount to the most recent amount.  Right?

Answer (score -1):

Though Not implemented it But can you try following :
Create two workflow rules on Opportunity which updates Account :

> 1)We've to first find if current opportunity is the first Opportunity created for for account and if it is, then somehow capture its amount 
>   a)create two  field isOpportunityExist(Checkbox, default unchecked) on Account and FirstOppAmount(Currency) on Account
>   b) workflow will fire only if isOpportunityExist = false , after workflow fire , update this field to 'true as well as populate FirstOppAmount field also. 
>   Now we've first opportunity amount available on Account
>
> 2) create another workflow on Opportunity 
>     a) for this also, first create new field say 'latestOppAmount' on Account
>     b) Create new workflow on opportunity ifiring on insert of every new opportunity(formula condition to evaluate workflow will be 'true', which ensure it fires on every insert) , this workflow updates field 'latestOppAmount' with Opportunity amount of every newly created Opportunity 
>    now you've , on account' Opportunity amount of most recently created Opportunity,

You can create formula field on Account to compare these two values.

> I'm assuming Opportunity amount is not changing after insert. But in case it is changing, 2nd worflow could be changed to fire on every insert/update. 
>   in that case, you can compare oldest Opportunity with Opp amount of most recently modified opportunity of that Account.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Thats similar to what we are doing now.  The issue is that we cant get the first and last opportunities within a certain date range like we could with formula fields in reports.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure, if any standard solution exist. You might have to look for VF page based solution which can solve this